# Clearing input field depending on callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I have simple script which contains two pages - script.php and function.php. Script.php contains one input field with ID **#code** , one link with ID **#submit** and jquery function

```
$('#submit').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
    url: 'function.php',
    type: "POST",
    data: "text=" + $("#code").val(),
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#info').html(data);              
            }
        });         
    return false;
    });
```

---

How can I clear **#code** input field value depending on the return result from function.php? 
For example, if query is incomplete function.php will only show message in **#info** field, but if query is complete script will show message and clear input field value.

Comment: What do you mean by complete and incomplete ?

Comment: How do you differ between a 'complete' and 'incomplete' query? What data does the php file return in both cases?

Comment: example: if user must enter email address function.php will check if address is valid or not. If it is valid then the message will be shown and input field cleared. If it is not valid then only the message will be shown. That is just an example. :)

Comment: In both cases php will return text. It can return somethin else if that is needed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider returning JSON data from function.php, so something like this

```
{"clearCode":"true","info":"Some HTML"}
```

Then you can use the jQuery function [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

This means you can return a boolean which decides whether to clear **#code** or not and also return some html for **#info**

Answer (score 0):

return any status from your php page like success or failure, and then check it in success method, because success is executed if ajax call is completed successfully regardless of result,

you can do

```
$('#submit').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
    url: 'function.php',
    type: "POST",
    data: "text=" + $("#code").val(),
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(data) {
        if (data == "success")
        {
            $("#code").value("");
        }
        else
        {
            $('#info').html(data);
        }
    }
    });         
    return false;
});
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

From your example, you could return a specific HTTP code:

In PHP:

```
if(not_valid) { Header("HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden"); die(); }
```

In JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({ ...,
         success: function() { /*ok*/ },
         statusCode: {
            403: function() { /*wrong*/ }
          }
      )};
```